# mysql simplifying select query from EAV with multiple joins (codeigniter)?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join, entity-attribute-value

The current code does not return all rows.

For example if some products don't have category or user activity are excluded from selected rows.

How to simplify that query with working one?

Is there a way to do it with multiple unions or any other (simple) way?

```
$q = $this->db->select('products.id, users_activity.timestamp AS added, products_content.lang, products_content.product_name, products_content.price, products_categories_content.category_name AS category, products_categories_content.category_id AS category_id')
        ->from('products')
        ->join('products_content', 'products.id = products_content.product_id')
        ->join('products_and_categories', 'products.id = products_and_categories.product_id')
        ->join('products_categories_content', 'products_categories_content.category_id = products_and_categories.category_id')
        ->join('users_activity', 'users_activity.id = products.id AND users_activity.lang = products_content.lang')->where('users_activity.type', 'product')
        ->group_by(array('products.id', 'products_content.lang', 'users_activity.id'))
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

if (strlen($query_array['lang']) && ! is_numeric($query_array['lang'])) { $q->like('lang', $query_array['lang']); }
if (strlen($query_array['product_name'])) { $q->like('product_name', $query_array['product_name']); }
if (strlen($query_array['category'])) { $q->where('category_id', $query_array['category']); }

$return['rows'] = $q->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, CI creates inner joins. Inner join only find results if a record is in both tables. So, if a product has no category then this statement will not return any records.

```
$this->db->join('products_and_categories', 'products.id = products_and_categories.product_id');
```

Change this join to a left join and products will always be returned, even if they have no categories.

```
$this->db->join('products_and_categories', 'products.id = products_and_categories.product_id', left);
```